# Battery problems with HP Spectre x360 (2019) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hp, battery, tlp

I have used Windows for around 7 months and I got around 7-15 hours battery life depends on the usage (Reading, Movies, Coding and etc.). I moved to Ubuntu everything is perfect except the battery life. I downloaded TLP but still. Today I have attended to online Lecture at 09:27 with 79% of battery life, brightness was on the middle, only one Chromium page was active with video and sound on that's all. At 11:30 it was 26% already. Please advice me what to do :(

Comment: Same problem here and it happened recently. I've progressively updated from 20.04 to 20.10 using the dev version of Ubuntu. And now my battery lasts 2-3. Before it could last easily 8-12 hours. The laptop is only one year old and as you describe the same problem, we can exclude a faulty battery (I guess).
My initial guess is a recent kernel update has a negative impact on the battery life.

Comment: I solved the issue by installing slimbook for saving battery, it worked well in Ubuntu 20.04, I got around 8-10 hour, then I updated to 20.10 same problem :D, please tell me as well in case you fix it :D